# React Native - Failed to load bundle in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

[image: Error Screen on opening of app]

I am native iOS app developer but i also want to be aware of latest and trending technology so i choose to get my hands on react native. Now, i am getting this error when trying to run my react native created app on iOS. I enter the command react-native run-ios and simulator started and after that app opened but in starting it showed this screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of solutions available in the link below. Please try them.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21310

```
for now after react-native init, since a lot of new changes are coming out, this fix worked for me (I got it from reading other issues):
with npm:
npm install --save-dev @babel/core
npm install --save-dev @babel/runtime
or with yarn:
yarn add --dev @babel/core
yarn add --dev @babel/runtime

if on ios you get _this._registerEvents is not a function, after a successful build
do
npm run start --reset-cache
or
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: Yes alot of thanks buddy. it did work for me and solved that issue.

Comment: You are welcome @ashish.surana. Please update the acceptance so it could be helpful to others who are facing the same issue.

Comment: Yeah actually only upvoted earlier but now i have made it correct. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

For me i got reason for issues that for now since a lot of new changes are coming out like Xcode 10 itself is new and react native is not yet merged with that, this fix worked for me:

with npm:

npm install --save @babel/runtime

or with yarn:

yarn add @babel/runtime